# using css -top value to move a div position

Tags: html, css

Hi I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but I am trying to position a div tag back
over the previous div element
This is what I have working

[image: example]

my css that I have used to get this to work looks like

```
.page-frame {
background-color: #fff;
padding-top: 40px;
position: relative;
top: -35px;
}
```

so for the top part the div element looks the way I want it to however the bottom on the element hasn't adjusted for the -35px;

[image]

I have tried adding a clear div after the element however that doesnt help. What do I need to change to remove the space between my .page-frame div and the next div?

Comment: It would help if you could make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code.

Comment: That gap looks about 40px tall. Can you see the number anywhere in your CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `position: relative` only shifts the appearance of the element in the page, but not the actual "space" it takes up on the page. So what you have done made your visual change to show the element `35px` higher, but it does not cause other elements to reflow around it. Probably, what you need to add is a `margin-bottom: -35px` to get the final effect you want.

**EDIT**: [Added better fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fLCKz/2/) to show reflow with margin.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: absolute;` instead of `relative`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position one element over some other one which is higher in the hierarchy, using **z-index** CSS property worth considering to use, see for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index